# Volume of water in a bowl $\pi\left(rh^2-\frac{h^3}{3}\right)$

Tags: calculus, volume

A friend from work found his old Maths exam from uni in the 1970's and I am giving it a bash! Im a bit stuck on a question so thought id ask the hive mind for some help!

A bowl is in the shape of a hemisphere of inside radiues $r$ cm. Initially the bowl is full of water which leaks through a small hole at its lowest point. Show that, when the water surface is at a height $h$ cm above the hole, the volume of water in the bowl is

$$\pi\left(rh^2-\frac{h^3}{3}\right) \text{cm}^3.$$ If the rate of leakage at that time is $\pi k{h^\frac{1}{2}}\text{cm}^3 / \text{sec}$, where $k$ is constant, show that the rate of fall of the surface is then $$\frac{k}{2rh^{\frac{1}{2}}-h^{\frac{3}{2}}} \text{cm\sec}.$$ Find the value of $h$ for which the rate of fall is least.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The volume of the water can be integrated with the disk method in cylindrical coordinates for the sphere $\rho^2+z^2= r^2 $,

$$V(h)= \int_{r-h}^r \pi \rho^2 (z)dz 
=  \pi\int_{r-h}^r (r^2-z^2) dz 
=\pi\left(rh^2-\frac{h^3}{3}\right) $$

Then, evaluate

$$\frac{dV}{dt} = \pi k{h^\frac{1}{2}}= \pi (2rh-h^2) \frac{dh}{dt} $$

which leads to the rate of surface fall

$$\frac{dh}{dt} = \frac{k}{2rh^{\frac{1}{2}}-h^{\frac{3}{2}}} \>\text{cm\sec}$$

Set $\frac{d^2h}{dt^2}=0$ to obtain $h=\frac 23r$ for the least rate of fall.

Comment: This is great - i knew i was missing something!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @maths1234 you’re welcome